# Will a PCIe generation 2 card work in a PCIe generation 3 slot?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

I have a PC with a PCIe generation 3 slot. The card I am looking at is PCIe generation 2. If I buy the older card will it work in the newer slot?

Comment: PCIe is backwards compatible.

Comment: @Ramhound I think backwards compatibility would cover a gen 3 card in a gen 2 slot, but I'm curious about whether it will work the other way around.

Comment: @Prinsig no, that would be forward compatibility

Comment: @Prinsig - You asked if a PCIe 2.0 card would work in a PCIe 3.0 slot.  You didn't ask about the "other way around" you ask about PCIe backwards compatibility and there are multiple questions about that topic already.

Comment: Please, ignore that comment because I worded it wrong. Is an older card in a newer slot considered forward or backward compatibility?